# Why isn't a gay marriage established in one state protected in other states by the Privileges and Immunities Clause?

Tags: united-states, us-constitution, marriage

Of course I know it's otherwise protected by the new *Respect for Marriage Act* and *Obergefell*, but I happened to be reading about the rather demure P&I Clause in Article 4. and it seemed relevant. IIUC, it's been used to guarantee that "fundamental" rights for a citizen of state A are recognized when travelling to all the other states. Is marriage not considered a fundamental right?

Comment: Not sure about how it "should" be in legal doctrine,  but by codifying it into law they prevent the judicial branch from interpreting the constitution/existing laws in some way that seems illogical but suits their objective for some reason....Not that that would ever happen.

Sometimes its good to have something explicitly be permitted rather than implicitly,  just so there is no question and no room for anyone to argue.

Comment: I guess I'm wondering why, before Obergefell, that clause wasn't used as the basis for a lawsuit by a couple from a gay-marriage-state who moved or was visiting a non-gay-marriage-state, and then had their spousal rights violated at a hospital during some health emergency because their marriage wasn't treated as valid.

Comment: I remember what I thought was an almost bizarre case where a judge refused to divorce a gay couple because they couldn’t be legally married in that state. I thought that was like an underage kid getting into a bar, starting a fight and they can’t throw him out because he is too young to be there in the first place.

Comment: @MattChambers This was one theory of many that was argued. There were dozens of cases addressing every possible theory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The relevant portion of the U.S. Constitution is the [full faith and credit clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_Faith_and_Credit_Clause#Application_to_family_law) (which the *Respect for Marriage* act is primarily an implementation and enforcement of). This requires states to honor marriages and divorces entered into in different states (subject to limited public policy exceptions that the *Respect for Marriage* act further limited), and also, for example, paternity determinations and court judgments from other states.

This was one argument among many used to argue that same sex marriages from other states should be recognized in other states. But the U.S. Supreme Court in *Obergefell v. Hodges*, [576 U.S. 644](https://www.oyez.org/cases/2014/14-556) (2015), in which it established a right to same sex marriage in all U.S. states, relied instead mostly upon a substantive due process clause analysis similar to that of *Loving v. Virginia*, [388 U.S. 1](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/388/1/) (1967), which held that bans on interracial marriage were unconstitutional.

The Article IV [privileges and immunities clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privileges_and_Immunities_Clause) protects very little (mostly the right to interstate travel and the right for an out of state resident to be licensed in a profession in a state).

The *Slaughterhouse cases*, [83 U.S. 36](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/83/36/) (1872), in the late 19th century gave a very crabbed interpretation to the 14th Amendment privileges and immunities clause, limited that only to rights arising from federal citizenship.

The logic of the *Slaughterhouse* line of cases spilled over into the privileges and immunities clause of Article IV of the U.S. Constitution. The Article IV privileges and immunities clause applies to rights specific to state citizenship to prevent those rights from being denied to out of state U.S. citizens. But those rights are few and far between, and court crafted exceptions have been carved out  in cases where it does exist (hunting and fishing license fees and college tuition, for example).

Comment: Do you know if a "full faith and credit" argument was ever tested in court prior to *Obergefell*?  I could only find mention of cases that were dismissed on standing.

Comment: @NateEldredge I know for certain that it was raised in trial courts prior to *Obergefell*, but I don't recall if it prevailed. At that time, the *Defense of Marriage Act* purported to permit states to disregard same sex marriages entered into in other states as an interpretation and enforcement of the full faith and credit clause by Congress, so any ruling in favor of a party based upon full faith and credit would have had to also find that the Defense of Marriage Act was unconstitutional. There were several dozen cases and I followed a good sampling of them. I might have citations somewhere.

Comment: @NateEldredge The DOMA barrier was ended in the *Windsor* case in 2012. https://www.oyez.org/cases/2012/12-307

Comment: @NateEldredge Pre-Windsor, a Maryland case resolved the question of recognition of a same same marriage validly entered into in another state on the parallel and related basis of comity rather than full faith and credit which DOMA purported to rule out. https://mdcourts.gov/data/opinions/coa/2012/69a11.pdf See also *Christiansen v. Christiansen*, 253 P.3d 153, 154 (Wyo. 2011) and *Dickerson v. Thompson*, 897 N.Y.S.2d 298, 299–301 (N.Y. App. Div. 2010).

Comment: Indeed, [according to this 1996 article](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/232622403.pdf), courts throughout the US often asserted as valid, but rarely ever actually applied, "public policy exceptions" (to the full faith and credit clause) as a basis for not recognizing a marriage (even going back to the days of anti-miscegenation laws). They very regularly recognized them under comity.

Comment: Somewhat off-topic, but could a comity doctrine approach to interstate respect of same-sex marriage have been applied from SCOTUS so that it would apply to all states?

Comment: I did search before asking the question for cases regarding same sex marriage and the P&I clause but came up blank. Possibly just bad search-fu. The key distinction seems to be whether the clause can require a state to respect the rights of non-residents based on the laws of their resident state, or if the clause only requires that a state confers the same rights to non-residents as it does to its residents. It's not clear to me that the latter is what is meant by the Article IV text or its AoC precursor, but it's clear that's how SCOTUS  has interpreted it since the Civil War.